# Getting started with a C# project to receive http messages

Tags: c#, http, python-requests

I am new to C# and would like to create a small application on Windows 10 that runs in the background and occasionally receives and processes a message (ON/OFF or 1/0 or JSON or something like that) from a PHP website on the local network.

What would be a suitable approach?
Do I need to create my own event handler?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into .NET WebAPI in .NET framework, for .NET core you can look into doing a normal MVC app, in .NET core MVC and WebAPI were merged into one. A MVC controller in your app then acts as your Restful endpoint you can call from your PHP website, just note on your endpoint you need to define the contract or object you are expecting to receive which makes it a bit safer that just accepting anything. And then in the MVC app you can then do whatever you need to whether its queueing something, sending the data to some other location or doing some processing then saving the information afterwards.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

[Calling ASP.NET Web Api method with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994893/calling-asp-net-web-api-method-with-php)

Comment: WebAPI or MVC should be hostable with either IIS as your webserver, or via self hosting option then you can run it as a console app or work it into a windows service which would then use kestrel to handle its web requests

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I should have specified that the application is a desktop app that moves to the foreground when the message is received.

Comment: You can still make use of webapi to host your endpoints in the background but then maybe use an event handler for forwarding info between the api to the app or if you want the app to perform something when the api is hit, webapi can be hosted with owin which can be started in your desktop app's startup. And also shutdown when your desktop app closes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions